# Is Traversable a trait or a class

Tags: scala, iterator, traversable

**Question 1 -**

In the Scala documentation, I found that Traversable is a trait with an abstract method `foreach`:

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html

Then, why could I instantiate an object of type Traversable?

```
val t = Traversable(1,2,3)

t.foreach(println _) //where is Scala picking foreach a definition from?
```

**Question 2 - how is Traversable different from other classes like List or Array? Does it come under Seq, Set or Map category ( I thought other collection inherit from Traversable)**

Question 3 - I could do exactly the same for the `Iterable` trait even though as per documentation, Iterable has an abstract method, `iterator`:

```
val v1 = Iterator(1,2,3)

v1.foreach( println _)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1: When you do `Traversable(1,2,3)`, you are actually calling the `apply`-method on the companion object of the `Traversable` trait. This method actually creates a `List` with the elements you provided (`List` extends `Traversable`). The `foreach` method you are calling is therefore actually the `foreach` method of `List`.

Question 2: Yes, `Traversable` is the trait at the top of the collections hierarchy in Scala. `List` and `Array` are actual examples of some concrete collections, while `Traversable` is a general trait that a lot of collections implement.

Question 3: `Iterable` and `Iterator` is not the same thing. You seem to mix them up in the question. `Iterable(1,2,3)` does the exact same thing as `Traversable(1,2,3)`. It calls the `apply` method on the companion object of `Iterable` and gives you a `List`. `Iterator(1,2,3)` however, calls the `apply` method on `Iterator`, and gives you a new `Iterator` that iterates through the 3 numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason to create a companion object? I cannot see a scenario where I will use an object of Traversable or Iterable.

Comment: The companion object usually contains some creators for the class. The companion object is always defined in the same file as the class, and it has the same name as the class. You can see the API docs for the companion object of `Traversable` here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Traversable$.html